# ELIFECYCLE error when "NPM I" Node.js

Tags: node.js

When I am trying to "NPM install" something, I keep getting the error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bufferutil@3.0.3 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@3.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-18T06_55_55_944Z-debug.log
```

Comment: please provide the package.json you are trying to install.

Comment: @Akhileshkrishnan https://pastebin.com/RkiDYd5u

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As of your question currently written you likely wont get any help.